# Apple Watch - Passbook "location aware" notification keeps appearing

Tags: notifications, geolocation, apple-watch, wallet

Ever since I went to a Starbucks and paid with the Passbook app, I keep getting (what I assume is) a location aware notification to use my Starbucks passbook app.

The trouble is that I keep getting this notification (for this particular store) whether I am actually near it or not! It's getting a bit annoying as I keep thinking I have a notification when I actually haven't. I will clear it, and after 10 minutes or so, it's back again! I am wondering if this is could also having a negative impact on battery life (I haven't noticed this though).

Any ideas on how I can stop it doing this? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The embarrassingly simple solution to the issue turned out to be a reboot :-|

Answer (score 0):

Go into the Apple Watch companion app on your iPhone, then go to Notifications->Passbook & Apple Pay and check "Custom", and then a "Show Alerts" switch will appear. Switch it off and you shouldn't be able to receive any more notifications for Passbook on your Apple Watch.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That should work... but for some reason it isn't!  That notification is still popping up every 10 minutes. Maybe a watchOS bug? I think it's finally time for me to restart my watch. See if that does the trick.

Comment: That's strange. Try going into Settings->Notifications->Passbook and then switch Allow Notifications to off.